# What are pixel size limits of GDI bitmaps/DCs in 32-bit and 64-bit processes?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I'm coding a Win32 application that performs low-level printing, for which I'm dealing with [GDI bitmaps and device contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx).

The code basically does this (pseudo-code):

```
HDC hCompDc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

BITMAPINFOHEADER infoHeader = {0};

infoHeader.biSize          = sizeof(infoHeader);
infoHeader.biWidth         = nWidth;
infoHeader.biHeight        = -nHeight;      //The document must be right side up
infoHeader.biPlanes        = 1;
infoHeader.biBitCount      = 24;
infoHeader.biCompression   = BI_RGB;

BITMAPINFO info;
info.bmiHeader = infoHeader;

//Use file on disk to store large bitmap data
HANDLE hFileScatch = ::CreateFile(strTempPath, 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

UINT64 ncbLineSz = nWidth * 3;
if(ncbLineSz & 0x3)
    ncbLineSz = (ncbLineSz & ~0x3) + 0x4;       //Must be DWORD aligned

UINT64 uiSzBmp = ncbLineSz * nHeight;

HANDLE hFileMapObj = ::CreateFileMapping(hFileScatch,
    NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, (DWORD)(uiSzBmp >> 32), (DWORD)(uiSzBmp), NULL);

BYTE* pMemory = 0;
HBITMAP hBitmap = ::CreateDIBSection(hDC, &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pMemory, hFileMapObj, 0);

::SelectObject(hCompDc, hBitmap);

//Do drawing on `hCompDc` using other GDI APIs
//...

//And print
::SetAbortProc(hPrintDC, _printerAbortProc);
::StartDoc(hPrintDC, &docInfo);
::StartPage(hPrintDC);

::BitBlt(hPrintDC, 
    rcPrintArea.left,
    rcPrintArea.top, 
    rcRenderArea.Width(), 
    rcRenderArea.Height(), 
    hCompDc,                    //DC from
    rcRenderArea.left,
    rcRenderArea.top,
    SRCCOPY);

::EndPage(hPrintDC);

//Clean up, etc.
//...
```

This works but to a certain degree. Let me explain:

Since I'm dealing with printer resolutions running at 300 dpi (vs. 96 dpi for a usual screen) the sizes of bitmaps turn out pretty large.

For instance, if I have a bitmap that is `3900`x`86625` pixels, it requires a DIB section of around `966 MB`. (I can learn that if I substitute default memory allocation in `CreateDIBSection` in my code above with a [`file mapping object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) backed by a [file on disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).) Otherwise, I understand that I can hit a limit of contiguous RAM space in a 32-bit process with that chunk of memory. But that is not what happens.

When I run my code with that size of a bitmap in a 32-bit process, the bitmap is created OK using [`file mapping object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) backed by a [file on disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), but the resulting bitmap/image comes out completely blank, while the exact same code compiled in a 64-bit process, produces a normal looking bitmap.

So in light of that I was curious if there are specific image size restrictions that those GDI objects have? For 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

And also a side question -- is there any way to know that such size limit was reached while drawing?

PS. My actual code has all error checks in place for all Win32 APIs, and while the 32-bit process that I described above produced a blank bitmap, it did not fail in a single GDI API.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just drawing on `hPrintDC` directly? And what does the file on disk show from the 32-bit process, also blank?

Comment: To disambiguate that second question, when you say the file on disk comes up blank, do you mean the printer spits out a blank page or if you view the image file on your computer you see nothing? Or both? If not both, what does doing the other show?

Comment: When people get error handling wrong, they usually don't know, that their error handling is wrong. Please show the real code.

Comment: The reason for a blank bitmap could be BitBlt failing. Have you checked the return value? GDI operations depend on kernel mode memory address space and depending on your OS config this could be as little as 1GB. I'm just guessing here, but BitBlt could require large amounts of (temporary) memory to perform the operation.

Comment: @andlabs: I did not say that a "file on disk" comes out blank. The bitmap does, i.e. all white, or all `0xffffff` pixels. As for using `hPrintDC` directly -- I need to break it into pages, i.e. separate lines. Thus the need for memory DC.

Comment: @SvenNilsson: You might be on to something. Do you know if that 1 GB is also the threshold for a x64 bit process? Because it doesn't seem to be an issue there.

Comment: Kernel mode memory is huge on x64, several terabytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space

Comment: @SvenNilsson: Well, that might explain it. Although one would hope that Microsoft documented it somewhere...