# how to implement duplex printing via GDI Print API

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to implement duplex printing on a printer. I set the DEVMODE structure in the printer driver with the dmDuplex parameter

```
int dvmSize=DocumentProperties(GetForegroundWindow(),hPrinter,(LPWSTR)(printerName.c_str()),NULL,NULL,0);
DEVMODE *dvmSettings = (DEVMODE*) GlobalAlloc(GPTR,dvmSize);
DEVMODE *dvMode = (DEVMODE*) GlobalAlloc(GPTR,dvmSize);
DocumentProperties(GetForegroundWindow(),hPrinter,(LPWSTR)(printerName.c_str()),dvmSettings,NULL,DM_OUT_BUFFER);
dvmSettings->dmDuplex=DMDUP_HORIZONTAL;
dvmSettings->dmFields=DM_DUPLEX;
DocumentProperties(GetForegroundWindow(),hPrinter,(LPWSTR)(printerName.c_str()),dvMode,dvmSettings,DM_IN_BUFFER|DM_OUT_BUFFER);
```

As far as I understand, there are 2 ways of implementation. Via WritePrinter or create a HDC using CreateDC passing dvMode and draw directly to the context. The second way is more convenient for me, but will it work? I'm asking because I can't test it right now and I need to know if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, it will work.

You could call the [CreateDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdca) or [PrintDlgEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms646942(v=vs.85)) function to get the printer DC.

If your application calls the CreateDC function, it must supply a driver and port name. To retrieve these names, call the [GetPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/getprinter) or [EnumPrinters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumprinters) function.

If your application calls the PrintDlgEx function and specifies the PD_RETURNDC value in the Flags member of the [PRINTDLGEX structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlgexa), the system returns a handle to a device context for the printer selected by the user.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Docs:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/sending-data-directly-to-a-printer
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/printdocs/gdi-printing
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-output
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes

Comment: @I101I Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN example mentioned above (1) is for sending real raw data to the printer.

[What are pixel size limits of GDI bitmaps/DCs in 32-bit and 64-bit processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340419/what-are-pixel-size-limits-of-gdi-bitmaps-dcs-in-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes)

This example helped me. It's similar steps to the MSDN example except it uses the printer's hdc instead of the printer's handle.

After executing StarDoc(pd.hDC) and StartPage(pd.hDC) you can use the pd.hDC to draw GDI commands. Its like a GetDC() or render_target->BeginDraw() opening statement that allows you to draw on the printer's DC. Executing EndPage() and EndDoc() is like ReleaseDC() or render_target->EndDraw().

This was a good find on stackoverflow for an unrelated question since trying to learn XPS API lead to a dead-end due to some deprecated functions and no good examples on how to use the IPrintDocument API with XPS API. However, learning how to use the D2D version of printing by using the CommandList was a successful venture.